# How can I create a SharePoint group using Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, flow

I want to use Flow to create SharePoint groups on one of my sites. From what I can tell, I should be using the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action but I know next to nothing about using REST API.

The closest answer I've found is this:

[How can I create a standard Sharepoint permission group using "send HTTP request to sharepoint](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/How-can-I-create-a-standard-Sharepoint-permission-group-using/td-p/169904).

which isn't really enough information for me to work this out on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need to use **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action in Microsoft Flow in order to create a SharePoint Group.

Try Using it as given in below image:

[image]

**Output**: Group with name **GroupFromFlow** is created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! What I had tried was pretty much that but I had some typos that I didn't pick up on. Having never done this before, I wasn't sure if I was even on the right track

Comment: Great, Glad it worked for you.